# Can you not order a dictionary by ordering the keys before creating it?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, dictionary, swift3

So I'm trying to get a dictionary `var billMap = [String: [Any]]()` because this goes into my UITableView. The keys of this dictionary are the sections and the value objects turn into the cells. Unfortunately, simply ordering the input data by `session` (what becomes the key of `billMap`) does not affect the order of the dictionary `billMap`:

```
let billArySorted = billAry.sorted(by: {
    ($0 as! [String: Any])["session"] as! String > ($1 as! [String:Any])["session"] as! String
})

var session = ""
for item in billArySorted {
    let dict = item as! [String:Any]
    if session != dict["session"] as! String {
        session = dict["session"] as! String
        var bills = billArySorted.filter({var billTemp: AnyObject = $0 as! AnyObject;  return billTemp["session"] as! String == session})
        var billsInSession = [AnyObject]()

        for bill in bills {
            let billObject: AnyObject = bill as! AnyObject
            billsInSession.append(billObject)
        }

        self.billMap[session] = billsInSession
    }
...
```

Any ideas? Thx

Comment: By definition, a dictionary is unordered.

Comment: Is there an alternative data structure that is ordered that you could recommend? C# has OrderedDictionary but I cannot find that here.

Comment: Use an array of dictionary or array of some other appropriate data.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. A dictionary does not have any order. The order in which you add the key/value pairs is irrelevant.

You need to use a different collection. An array of dictionaries should work, as rmaddy suggests.

Comment: And by the way, resist the urge to look at the order in which you get back values from a dictionary and write code that relies on it. It might appear to work and then later betray you. Don't do that.